# "Azure Bot" unavailable in "App Service" Application - HTTP status code Services Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-webapps

I've deployed the Azure Bot Ressource and the App Services Ressource in one Azure Ressource Group with Terraform.
The Multi Tenant Chatbot is written in python 3.7 using FLASK. Locally its running on the Bot Emulator smoothly.
Azure Bot is deployed in the "global" Location, app services in "westeurope". I followed the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#publish-c-bot-on-app-service-plan-from-visual-studio) for the deployment.

Using the Web Chat, I'm receiving the following:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code
> Service Unavailable

Ive already checked the following points:

- Messaging endpoints (https + identical)
- MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword are correct
- App Service --> TLS/SSL settings --> HTTPS Only --> On

What else can I check? It seems like something within the Bot Service Registration went wrong.

Application URL:

[image: Application URL]

Web chat error messages:

[image: Web Chat error]

Azure Bot Properties:

[image: Azure Bot Properties]

Azure bot Configuration:

[image: Azure bot Configuration]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems to me things changed behind Azure Bot Service. I'm trying to figure out the 'new' way to deploy a bot built with Bot Service. You can follow this on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6446#issuecomment-1009345884

Comment: @Thiago Custodio thanks for the response. Ive seen this on Github... now we successfully linked the bot and the app service. We did it with the Bot Composer. No we're running into the following: "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized" so with the right credentials we might solve it :)